# Footnote rule y position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, footnotes, footer

How can I obtain the absolute y position (height) of the footnote rule?

I want to draw (using TikZ) a box from a command to the end of the text in the page, without considering the footnotes. This position is not fixed: it depends on the number of footnotes.

[image: Current result/expected result]

This is a small working example with the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,positioning}

\definecolor{cpp}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\newcommand{\createline}{
    \pgfmark{begincreateline}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path ({pic cs:begincreateline}-| current page text area.west) ++(0pt,-0.5em) coordinate(A);
        \path (current page text area.south west) coordinate(B); % should be until the footrule!
        \fill[color=black] ($(A) + (-.2cm, 0pt)$) rectangle ($(B) + (-.7cm, 0pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\lipsum[1-1]

\createline

Some text with footnote\footnote{Text}. Another footnote\footnote{Other}.

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be a work for tcolorbox.

Comment: I think I tried using tcolorbox a long time ago... I don't remember what was the problem with it that made me use TikZ. The truth is that I use this box on the margin for an environment (instead of a command) - and the environment may span for several pages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This modifies `\footnoterule` to add a tikzmark to the left.   The actual line is 3pt-2.6pt above the baseline.

You might also look at `\iftikzmark`, but that shouldn't be an issue in this case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,positioning}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\footnoterule}{\pgfmark{footrule\thepage}}{}{FAILED}

\definecolor{cpp}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\newcommand{\createline}{%
    \pgfmark{begincreateline\thepage}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path ({pic cs:begincreateline\thepage}-| current page text area.west) ++(0pt,-0.5em) coordinate(A);
        \path (pic cs:footrule\thepage) coordinate(B); % should be until the footrule!
        \fill[color=black] ($(A) + (-.2cm, 0pt)$) rectangle ($(B) + (-.7cm, 3pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\lipsum[1-1]

\createline

Some text with footnote\footnote{Text}. Another footnote\footnote{Other}.

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This works perfectly! I tried several solutions for months.